# What type of Probability is that? How to solve it? Suggested Readings?

Tags: probability

You choose a point (X; Y ) uniformly at random in the unit square.

$S = \{(x; y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \le x \le 1; 0 \le y \le 1 \}$

Let A be the event $\{(x, y) \in S : |x-y| \le \frac{1}{2}\}$ and B be the event $\{(x, y) \in S : y \ge x \}$

(a) Show sets A and B in the x-y plane.

(b) Find P(A) and P(B).

(c) Are A and B independent?

Comment: Can you say more specifically what you're having problems with? Can you say more specifically what progress you've made so far, and where you're stuck? There are three parts to the question; the first one should be done before the other two. Can you draw a sketch of a graph showing sets S, A and B?

Comment: @EricLippert Hi, no unfortunately, I can't.

Comment: Can you draw a sketch showing S?

Comment: @EricLippert no.

Comment: S is a square. Can you draw a square?

Comment: yes I can draw a square.

Comment: Do you know what the coordinate plane looks like?  Two axes, labeled x and y, at right angles to each other, with number lines on them?

Comment: @EricLippert can you give me some links to reading materials so I can easily understand and solve myself this type of questions. I think I am missing some basics.

Comment: All you've given us is the problem, that you don't know how to solve it, and that you know how to draw a square. It is really hard to give recommendations when we don't know what level you're at. It's a probability problem; do you know what a probability is?

Comment: @EricLippert yes you are right. That is the case actually I don't know myself. I have studied probability, calculus I/II, statistics etc a long ago. Now having some trouble.

Comment: @EricLippert and I am really sorry If I put you in confusion. I am new to this community please accept my apologies.

Comment: This is basic probability. Any introductory text should cover this.

Comment: @JohnDouma okay thanks!

Comment: There's no need to apologize, but understand that this site is not for tutorials and not a referral service; it's for answering *specific questions that have specific answers*. It sounds like you need a refresher in the basics, and that's fine, but this isn't the site for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments on this answer indicate you may not fully understand what you are being asked, I'll instead go over what the question is actually asking:

> You choose a point (X; Y ) uniformly at random in the unit square.
>
> $S = \{(x; y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \le x \le 1; 0 \le y \le 1 \}$

Here, $S$ is the unit square described in the first sentence.  Note that "unit square" means "a 1 unit by 1 unit square", where "1 unit" is some arbitrary, (usually) irrelevant unit.  Basically, if you draw a simple graph, your unit square will be formed by points (0,0) and (1,1).

> Let A be the event $\{(x, y) \in S : |x-y| \le \frac{1}{2}\}$ and

$|x-y|$ means, "the absolute value of $x-y$.  So, an element will be in A if $|x-y| \le \frac{1}{2}$.  I encourage you to draw $|x-y| = \frac{1}{2}$ on a simple graph.  All points on one side of that drawing will be in A.  If you have trouble drawing it, try choosing arbitrary values for X (with x between 0 and 1), then finding values for y that work.  If you draw enough points, you'll probably see a pattern.  Similarly, if you're not sure which side of the separator is in A, just test a few points.

> B be
>   the event $\{(x, y) \in S : y \ge x \}$

Follow the advice for A, but this time do it for B.

> (a) Show sets A and B in the x-y plane.

Conveniently, I've already instructed you how to do this above.

> (b) Find P(A) and P(B).

P(A) = Area(A) / Area(S).
P(B) = Area(B) / Area(S).
(Area(S) is 1, since it's a unit square).

If your drawing is accurate, you can use simple geometry to calculate Area(A) and Area(B).  Possibly your instructor is expecting you to use integrals instead (that's a bit dirty since you're dealing with absolute values), though doing so gives the same result.

> (c) Are A and B independent?

This is asking whether knowing a point is in or not in A gives influences the probability of a point being in B.  You should be able to determine this by visual inspection.  Translating such an inspection into math via simple geometry should be straightforward.

Comment: Hi brian, thank you very much for clarifying. Let's say for $y \ge x : $ I will have a lot of possibilities. for instance if I take x = 0.1 then there are a lot of values of y greater than x. Do I have to sum all the possibilities and while calculating area? As you said it's a bit dirty!

Comment: @Tigereno: Summing all the possibilities to calculate area is *calculus*, but you can solve this problem without calculus.  Again, draw a sketch. You'll discover that the set S, which is "all points (x, y) where x and y are both between 0 and 1" is a square. The subset of that set which is all points where y >= x, if you draw it, you will discover is a triangle, and you know how to find the area of a triangle.

Comment: @Tigereno: I hinted at this in my description above, but I'll be more explicit.  If you want to graph an equation containing an inequality, just graph the equality instead.  In other words, the way to graph `y≥x` is to graph `y=x`.  The `≥` just tells you which side of the line needs to be colored in.  To color in the graph, find a single point where `y>x`  (e.g., `1>0`), then color in everything on that side of the line.  If you don't know how to graph `y=x`, you may be in a situation where you have not met some of the (possibly unspoken) requirements for the material.